# Equivalence relation- Equivalence Classes And Partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I had the following question

A is a finite set and $R \subseteq A  \times  A$ is a equivalence relation.

Prove that $|A|$ is odd iff $|R|$ is odd.

I am trying to find a general formula for this question, Because I think it is true to a even set too.
Anyone have an idea?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

$R$ contains the set $Q=\{(x,x); x\in A\}$ which has as many elements as $A$. Try proving that  $R\setminus Q$ has an even number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** If $R_i$ are the equivalence classes of $R$, then $|R|=\sum|R_i|^2$ and $|A|=\sum|R_i|$. Look at both sums $\bmod 2$.

Comment: what I have thought about is that due to the fact that equivalence relation is a. reflective and b. is symmetric the general form will be 2K+1M meaning the ordered paris + the member of the set